# Call class method from event triggered inside an attribute object

Tags: python, multithreading, events, event-handling, python-multithreading

I have a class `ContainedClass` that is an attribute of a `Container` class. This `ContainedClass` has an event method that is triggered from a thread not controlled by my program (it is activated when it receives a message from an external source. A swig "C++" external library controls it). Both are defined in different modules.

**ContainedClass.py**

```
class ContainedClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        pass # Executed on external thread
```

**Container.py**

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, cc: ContainedClass, clients):
        self.cc = cc
        self.clients

    def do_stuff_on_cc_receiving_message(self):
        pass
```

Possible not so elegant solution: Passing `Container` as a parameter to `ContainedClass`.

Comment: It isn't unelegant to pass in the container to the container class if that's what is required.

Comment: But that makes the ContainedClass a container class of the Container class... I guess there's a better solution. I can't even type hint it because `Container.py` has `import ContainedClass` and `ContainedClass.py` would have `import Container`

Comment: Yeah, that would generate a circular dependency. Maybe you need to redesign the model and put the event loop in the container rather than the contained, or else put them in the same file.